# WPF: How to clone an image multiple times in a loop?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-4.5

Goal: To clone an image multiple times.

Problem: It gets an exception:

> An exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in
>   PresentationCore.dll but was not handled in user code Additional
>   information: Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the
>   program.

Question: How to do it in a right way?

Code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        double width = 1000;

        Ellipse ellipse = new Ellipse();
        ellipse.Width = width;
        ellipse.Height = width;
        ellipse.Fill = Brushes.Red;
        ellipse.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, width, width));

        RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)width, (int)width, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
        rtb.Render(ellipse);

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            rtb.Clone(); // Exception
    }
}
```

Comment: _Goal: To clone an image multiple times_ why do you want to do that?

Comment: The code is done simple to make it easy to understand. In my real situation, i create animation by frames. This code is not useful itself, it is just an example.

Comment: You are allocating at least 4 billion bytes worth of bitmap data in quick succession and you're wondering why `OutOfMemoryException` is thrown?

Comment: in quick succession - I feel it is a key point of the problem, but i don't know how to do it in not quick succession. I don't ask for solution to allocate it exactly in a way I show in my code, I ask - What is a right way to allocate it?

Comment: @Ziya The right way depends on what you actually want to do. You probably dont want to show all images at the same time. What about creating them on the fly when you actually need them? Also, how about creating your animation differently, for example by moving your image position instead of creating a copy with modifications? As others already pointed out, you probably *don't want to clone images* but you want to do something and you think that cloning images is the way to go.

Comment: What about creating them on the fly - images are too heavy. moving your image position - my animation is not about moving an image. You mean there are better ways, but you should admit that there are also many cases when we need to have animation based on frames and WPF has ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames that I use. I also use generating vector animation on fly, but I also need to use frame based animation. Both have right places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For best results, you should ask questions that pertain to real-world problems. It is simply not believable that one would need to clone a bitmap 1000 times in a tight loop like that.

That said, the answer is fairly easy: you are going too fast for the garbage collector to keep up. It hasn't discarded the previously-allocated memory before you hit the maximum size of the heap.

You have at least two possible ways to fix the problem. One is to change your loop so that you are forcing garbage collection periodically (e.g. every time you clone the bitmap):

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        rtb.Clone(); // Exception
        GC.Collect();
    }
```

Alternatively, you can just run the project as a 64-bit process, in which case it has plenty of address space to use for your 4GB's worth of allocations.

Comment: Small addition: `GC.Collect()` will not dispose the image immediately, so it is still possible to have `OutOfMemoryException` with this code. You should add `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();`

Comment: Aslo running GC 1000 times is bad idea. Rigth way is to manully dispose unused images

Comment: @DmitryDovgopoly: The entire idea of creating 1000 bitmaps in a row is bad; adding the `GC.Collect()` is inconsequentially bad in context. Your other comment (_"will not dispose the image immediately"_) is incorrect, as `RenderTargetBitmap` is not `IDisposable` and has no finalizer. There is no need to call `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()` here.

Comment: `RenderTargetBitmap` stores all the image data in `SafeMILHandle` and the base class `SafeHandle` has a finalizer. [Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/Media/Imaging/RenderTargetBitmap.cs)

Comment: @Dmitry: _"Rigth way is to manully dispose unused images"_ -- let's assume that the `SafeMILHandle` object is not somehow disposed of automatically. How then, do you propose client code "manually dispose unused images"? I don't have time to sift through the code base deciphering the implementation, but I find it remarkable to say the least to think that Microsoft would have chosen to _rely_ on the non-deterministic finalizer for disposal of unmanaged resources. Even allocating 10,000 clones I witnessed no problem calling `Collect()` w/out `WaitForPendingFinalizers()`.